Getting an error in prisma handled database code: Invalid `prisma.server.create()` invocation:
I'm creating a Discord clone and I've never used Prisma before. I've followed all the things mentioned on the Prisma and MongoDB site to use Prisma for MongoDB database. This is a NextJS 14 Project with typescript. Also, I've mentioned the erorr and all the details regarding the project and environment.
Environment variables loaded from .env
prisma                  : 5.11.0
@prisma/client          : 5.11.0
Computed binaryTarget   : windows
Operating System        : win32
Architecture            : x64
Node.js                 : v20.10.0
Query Engine (Node-API) : libquery-engine efd2449663b3d73d637ea1fd226bafbcf45b3102 (at node_modules\@prisma\engines\query_engine-windows.dll.node)
Schema Engine           : schema-engine-cli efd2449663b3d73d637ea1fd226bafbcf45b3102 (at node_modules\@prisma\engines\schema-engine-windows.exe)
Schema Wasm             : @prisma/prisma-schema-wasm 5.11.0-15.efd2449663b3d73d637ea1fd226bafbcf45b3102
Default Engines Hash    : efd2449663b3d73d637ea1fd226bafbcf45b3102
Studio                  : 0.499.0

But I'm getting an error here:
[SERVERS_POST] PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.server.create()` invocation:

{
  data: {
    profileId: "6604270fb6faae8d7cb1db0a",
    name: "Goal",
    imageUrl: "https://utfs.io/f/ca54e078-a1cc-4828-9471-94bb9fe367c3-1bos3.jpg",
    inviteCode: "0992bd52-caa1-4333-a37d-704fe215ad6f",
    channels: {
      create: [
        {
          name: "general",
          profileId: "6604270fb6faae8d7cb1db0a"
        }
      ]
    },
    members: {
      create: [
        {
          profileId: "6604270fb6faae8d7cb1db0a",
          role: "ADMIN"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Argument `serverId` is missing.
    at Tn (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:115:5888)
    at In.handleRequestError (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:6510)
    at In.handleAndLogRequestError (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:6188)
    at In.request (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:5896)
    at async l (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:127:10871)
    at async POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/servers/route.ts:25:24)
    at async E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63809
    at async eU.execute (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53964)
    at async eU.handle (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:65062)
    at async doRender (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1315:42)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1537:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1445:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1842:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1880:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:893:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:269:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:789:17)
    at async E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:331:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:151:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:328:24)
    at async invokeRender (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:174:21)
    at async handleRequest (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:353:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:377:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (E:\Projects\discord-clone\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:140:13) {
  clientVersion: '5.11.0'
}

import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { MemberRole } from "@prisma/client";

import { currentProfile } from "@/lib/current-profile";
import { db } from "@/lib/db";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const { name, imageUrl } = await req.json();
    const profile = await currentProfile();

    if (!profile) {
      return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }

    const server = await db.server.create({
      data: {
        profileId: profile.id,
        name,
        imageUrl,
        inviteCode: uuidv4(),
        channels: {
          create: [{ name: "general", profileId: profile.id }],
        },
        members: {
          create: [
            {
              profileId: profile.id,
              role: MemberRole.ADMIN,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });

    return NextResponse.json(server);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("[SERVERS_POST]", error);
    return new NextResponse("Internal Error", { status: 500 });
  }
}

schema.prisma
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Profile {
  id    String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId String  @unique
  name  String
  imageUrl String @db.String
  email String @db.String

  servers Server[]
  members Member[]
  channels Channel[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Server{
  id    String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name String 
  imageUrl String @db.String
  inviteCode String @db.String

  members Member[]
  channels Channel[]

  profile Profile @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id], onDelete:Cascade)
  profileId String @db.ObjectId
  
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@index([profileId])
}

enum MemberRole {
  ADMIN
  MODERATOR
  GUEST
}

model Member{
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  role MemberRole @default(GUEST)

  profile Profile @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  profileId String @db.ObjectId

  server Server @relation(fields: [serverId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  serverId String @db.ObjectId

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@index([profileId])
}

enum ChannelType{
  TEXT
  AUDIO
  VIDEO
}

model Channel{
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name String
  type ChannelType @default(TEXT)

  profile Profile @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  profileId String @db.ObjectId

  server Server @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id],  onDelete: Cascade)
  serverId String @db.ObjectId

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@index([profileId])
  @@index([serverId])
}

I've also tried to raising the issue on the Prisma Github respository. You can also checkout this error here: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/23681
